# My Site Url Question

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, url, mysite

We set up MySites (or my predesscor did) and the url is https://sp13mysites, but we would like it to sit below our main site. Is there a way to change the url and move it to (virtually) sit below main site - the new url we want is https://mainsite/mysites

Before I start I would like to know if it possible and anything I need to change besides AAM and bindings.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend this. MySites should be separate from your primary team/general sites. That said, you'd to do a few things on your primary Web Application:

1) Enable Self Service Site Creation

2) Create an Explicit Managed Path of '/mysites'

3) Create a wildcard path of where your MySites will be stored (e.g. '/personal').

4) Create a MySite Host site at https://mainsite/mysites

Next, you would need to go to your User Profile Service Application -> Setup MySites and modify the values appropriately.

Because you've enabled Self Service Site Creation, you're likely going to want to create a [database router](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-specifying-content-database-for-new-site-collections-when-using-host-named-site-collections) which will route MySites into the appropriate database(s) rather than intermixing with your standard sites.